# Java memory usage sandbox

Tags: java, memory-management, sandbox

I am trying to write a sandbox for an untrusted java code.
I wrote the sandbox using java. The sandbox is required to :

> 1. limit memory usage of the untrusted code. If the untrusted code uses more memory than a specified limit, the sandbox should terminate the program.
> 2. If the untrusted code does not exceed the specified limit, the sandbox should also be able to determine the "maximum memory peak" used.

Btw, when I said memory here, it means heap + non-heap memory.

I found that you can set memory threshold and be notified if **one** of memory pool exceeded the threshold. But this is not what I wanted, because I want to set the limit for Heap + Non-Heap memory.

The only solution I currently have is poll each small milliseconds, get heap + non-heap memory using getHeapMemoryUsage() and getNonHeapMemoryUsage() from [MemoryMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.html), and check whether it has exceeded the limit.

But I know  this solution is definitely not good too (and has flaws). Is there any other better solution?

Answer (score 5):

A single JVM has a shared heap among all threads.  You cannot "sandbox" memory.  You'll have to run a separate process if you wish to manage memory per application.

Now if you want to limit overall memory (Heap + non-heap) you can call the system function [setrlimit](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit) (if you are running Linux) via [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna), or you can call [ulimit](http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html) before you run the Java process.

To find out how much memory your process is using get the CommittedVirutalMemorySize attribute from [ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html) (but there's not a getter for it).

If you want to be notified of an impending shutdown, use the soft-limit for setrlimit/ulimit.  Your process will periodically get a [signal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/signals.html) that it has exceeded the soft-limit.  If you set a hard-limit and it is exceeded, the process will be killed.

EDIT: Added paragraphs about getting memory size and setrlimit signals.

Comment: Ok, so suppose I have managed to use JNA. How do I get to know the program crashed or not? Moreover, How do I get the maximum memory used, if it doesn't crash?

Comment: I added some content to my answer in response to your questions.  I don't have experience trying to get Java to respond to signals, so I can't say if that'll work well for you.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this is possible without deep magic: Either re-writing the bytecode of the untrusted code, or modifying the underlying JVM to track memory usage.

As an experiment, I've implemented the former (rewriting bytecode) in order to limit the memory allocations (and instruction-consumption) of untrusted code, using `-javaagent`s to re-write the bytecode of the java classes at load-time and insert checks before each and every memory allocation.

With this we are able to call a function and limit that function (and anything it calls) to, e.g. 1024 bytes of memory allocation and 10000 instructions, causing it to throw and exception if it overshoots. The kinda-sorta working code is available at

https://github.com/lihaoyi/6858

tl; dr: it's pretty damn hard. Not impossible, but it's not something you would try doing if you have deadlines to meet, and you could probably publish a conference paper if you truly got it working.